# Javascript to change table tab font color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have below Table section appears into my dashboard and I want to change color for the tab names as "TEST" :
NOTE : Below HTML is predefined and generate by tool so this can't be modified

```html
<table class="masterH3 masterTabBarTabSecondarySelected secondaryTabSelected tabContainerSelected" id="dashboard_page_6_tab" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td title="TEST">
        <div tabindex="0">TEST</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to change FONT color of TEST to any color I want and I have used below definition in Javascript to change color and override it

This JS works for Chrome and Edge but broken for Firefox for some reason. Any help to use alternative code to fix this ?
thanks

```js
var span1 = document.querySelector('#dashboard_page_6_tab span');
span1.innerHTML = '<font color="#F38A00"> TEST </font>';
```

Comment: Hm .. you are referring to the span tag, but this tag is not in your html. Or span dynamic?

Comment: I create separate Jquery script to override the TEST text color ... let me make some correction

Comment: But this is vanilla javascript, not jquery. But not the point is important :) Please tell us where the span tag comes from? - `#dashboard_page_6_tab span`

Comment: unfortunately I don't see any span tag ... probably because of upgrade this tag has been removed and replaced and still it is working somehow in Edge and Chrome but Firefox throwing errors ... I don't have any affinity to keep this code if we have alternate option please :)

Comment: I can see the span tag you are referring to in the js code - `var span1 = document.querySelector('#dashboard_page_6_tab span');`. Maybe you should write like this? - `var span1 = document.querySelector ('# dashboard_page_6_tab tr td div');`.

Comment: Or `<div tabindex="0"><span>TEST</span></div>` ?

Comment: Let me try JS change ... but I can't change anything under <div> .those are predefined code  ...change has to be in javascript

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov - sorry doesn't work in FF

Comment: Why did you test my code then, if the html structure cannot be changed?! In my example, I changed the html structure. Please make html the way it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation with the `span` tag remained unclear.

I took a different approach to creating the font tag, method `createElement()`. And then I assign the text, and the color style.

Check it out.

```js
var div_tag = document.querySelector('#dashboard_page_6_tab tr td div');
var div_tag_text = div_tag.innerText.trim();
var span_tag = document.createElement('span');

span_tag.style.color = '#F38A00';
span_tag.append(div_tag_text);
div_tag.innerHTML = '';
div_tag.append(span_tag);
```

```html
<table class="masterH3 masterTabBarTabSecondarySelected secondaryTabSelected tabContainerSelected" id="dashboard_page_6_tab" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td title="TEST">
        <div tabindex="0">TEST</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you . While your code might correct but I have no option to add customize the table the way I like. It is predefined code and there is no way I can tweak that . I can only override it with additional JS that I want to pass . with or without <span> in <div> doesn't work either unfortunately in FF .

Comment: @pauldx, Let's define .. Does your default div look like this? - `<div tabindex = "0"> TEST </div>` Or so? - `<div tabindex = "0"></div>`.

Comment: <div tabindex="0">TEST</div> is default <div>

Comment: Why on earth are you writing code - and I realise you’re providing the answer to the question, and you’re not the author that question - that creates an element that was deprecated in HTML 4.01? The best “*different approach*” would be to advise against use of the [‘<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) element.

Comment: @pauldx, Hi. I changed the concept of the code a bit. Now, the call is to tag - `<div tabindex = "0"></div>`. In this `div` tag, the dynamic `span` tag is created, and with the styles and text that was originally removed in the code. Check it out.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov - Thank you and sorry for delay . this perfectly works for both browsers . Sweet Solution !

Comment: Don't worry about the delay. All right. Happy to help :)